# Ignoring acent characters using Linq dynamically with EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a system that will get information from a database in default collation.

However the user can choose whether or not to save the text with or without accentuation (for example: "opção").

I want to create a function that will search for the text requested by the user and ignore the accented characters.

For example:

Filter: "opção"

Database data:

```
+----+------------+
| Id |    Text    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Opcao      |
|  2 | Opção      |
|  3 | informação |
|  4 | INFORMAÇÃO |
|  5 | OPÇÃO      |
+----+------------+
```

If I search for the word "opção" the EF Core must consider the text "op[çã|ca]o", like a regex expression and ignore the case sensitive.

On this example if I search for "opção" the EF Core must return the Ids: 1, 2 and 5.

Do you know any way to do this using EF Core with SQL Server?

P.S.: I don't have the permission to change database collation

Thanks

Comment: What *is* the collation of the column?

Comment: @Igor SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: There is no built in way to do this in EF (core or otherwise), you would have to build that out. In sql I believe you can cast the collation of a column in the query itself although it could be a problem if you rely on indexes on that column for performance. Do a search on how to query a accent sensitive column with an accent insensitive search, you should find some help there.

Comment: And in EF you would have to execute a raw sql query *or* you could add code that could be translated into a store expression. The latter is easier to reuse but will take an upfront investment to get working.

Comment: Why not just an accent-insensitive collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI?  eg `select 1 where N'Opção' = 'Opcao' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I cannot change anything on database, so I need to solve the problem on the API side

Comment: You can specify the collation in the query, although if it doesn't match the column collation you won't be able to use indexes.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Do you have an exemple to do this with EF Core?

Comment: If you don't set the column collation, you'll have to use Raw SQL Queries in EF to specify a different collation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql